# How to make a PDF form that accepts Images

Tags: javascript, pdf, image-uploading

I hope this question hasn’t been asked to death, but I’ve done a good amount of searching and just stumbled upon questions people asked regarding inserting images into PDF forms they have gotten for their particular project.

This is what I’m trying to do: 
I need to create a PDF form that allows people to drag and drop images or to choose an image file from their computer and to place it into the PDF. The problem I have had with the more common solutions is that these solutions only accept PDF images, but the form I’m trying to create is specifically for people that aren’t computer savvy so they likelihood of them having PDF images is very unlikely.

I found a solution on another site that says that inserting this code will work, but I have never used Javascript inside a pdf before.

```
event.target.buttonImportIcon();
```

But for some reason it only works on my end. If I complete the form’s creation and open the file from my computer it works exactly as I thought it would. Allowing me to add JPEGs, PNGs, etc to the document, but when I send the form to my coworkers, none of them are prompted to select an image from their computer, it just does nothing.

Comment: Without seeing the form, one guess could be that you have JavaScript enabled in your PDF viewer and your co-workers do not. Check in Edit->Preferences

Comment: @KevinBrown ...or, of course, they use different PDF viewers to start with. Different PDF viewers may support JavaScript to a different extend.

Answer (score 1):

@Daouzin

I have been searching for the same answer and this is what I've found.  I know I am about 2 months late but perhaps this will help anyway.

You are correct in using the `buttonimporticon()` method.

However there are 2 things you should know:

1. This function can only be used by a client who has Reader XI. No other past version of Reader will work.
2. The user can **only** import PDF files. In the past any file type could be imported, but not now. So you would have to train them on how to convert their picture to PDF format (pretty easy) and then the picture can be imported.

I got all of the above information from various threads in the Adobe forum.